# Using a string for an object name in a loop in R

Tags: r

I want to save several objects in a loop in separate files, but I have problems getting it right. Below is the code (a highly simplified example of the thing I am doing). I want the objects a2014 and b2014 to be saved to a2014.Rdata and b2014.Rdata. The code clearly does not work as the object *parametername* is saved and not the objects a2014 and b2014.

```
for (i in c("a","b")) {
   data <- c(1,2)
   parametername <- paste0(i,"2014")
   assign(parametername, data)
   save(parametername, file = paste0(i, "2014.Rdata")) # This is clearly not working
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Renger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the object name in `list`.

```
for (i in c("a","b")) {
  data <- c(1,2)
  parametername <- paste0(i,"2014")
  assign(parametername, data)
  save(list = parametername, file = paste0(i, "2014.Rdata")) 
}
```

Comment: If I run your first example, this is not working. I want the data to be saved as a2014 and b2014. In your example it is saved as data1.

Comment: Yes, the values are saved in `data1` but when I run the first part of my code there are objects called `a2014` and `b2014` in my global environment. As well as `a2014.Rdata` and `b2014.Rdata` in my working directory.

Comment: Sorry, missed that one. Thanks. However, I really would like to have them also saved as a2014 and b2014 automatically.

Comment: @arnyeinstein They are already saved as `a2014` and `b2014` automatically. After you run the above code type `a2014` in the console to see it. That is what first part of my answer is doing.

Comment: Yes, but if you restart or remove a2014 and b2014 and load a2014.Rdata, there is no a2014. Only a data1. I want a2014 to be saved as a2014 in the loop.

Comment: Got it. I have updated the answer to include that behaviour. Hope that helps.

Comment: I owe you a beer or a good glass of wine! Thanks